# How can I change the font size of KDE menus and dialogs...?

Tags: configuration, kde, fonts

In Ubuntu I have installed the KDE app `Konsole`.
I want to change the default font size of the KDE menus and dialogs, etc... to be larger.
(I don't mean the font in the Konsole's terminal window.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer (It works!)...
It is done via a **KDE** package called: **systemsettings**  ...(Synaptic)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Settings):

***System Settings** is a program where you can configure many parts of your desktop.

 Color, style, shortcuts and many other things. It takes the place of KDE 3's KControl.*

Comment: Wow! Bravo! This is me giving you a digital cookie, keep up the good work!